# A verb for the quick head-turning of a bird

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm sure the reader has seen a bird move its head about, no? When a bird is curious or wary, it moves its head about quickly, almost jerkily.

I have thought of using these words: *bob*, *wrench*, *flick*, *tilt*, *wag*, *shift*, *waggle*, *pump*, *snap*, *flip*, and *dip*. I like a few of them, but I was hoping some of you fine people could provide a word with better specificity.

In a sentence:

> The crow *flicked* its head about, wary of my presence, gawking at me with beady eyes.

Comment: I cam imagine a bird _bobbing_ its head (based on my recollection of my _readings_). You should also list the _few others_ that you considered (and apparently discarded) so that answerers don't waste their time with those words.

Comment: Like this example from the [verb definition 1.1 of bob](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bob) in ODO: `‘The bird bobs its head, showing more interest in its surroundings than the man who sustains an unaffected stare.’`

Comment: I always assumed the word 'bob,' in its verb form, meant to duck one's head up and down. What I picture as a bird moves its head around is it turning side to side, staring at its target with one eye. Regardless, 'bob' does have a nice ring to it and I suppose in such a simple action, there must be some room for freedom in the movement.

Comment: I realize now that perhaps a single word is not entirely appropriate... A phrase may better suit my request, and I believe that my answer lies in my very question. _Flick its head about_, _its head bobbed about_, etc.. These are more specific and I think provide a clear picture of what the bird is doing.

Comment: "When a bird is curious or wary, it moves its head about quickly, almost jerkily." - the way I read it a few decades ago, the eyes of (some kinds of?) birds are special and they actually *need* to actively move the head to be able to see static, non-moving stuff. If they were to hold their heads perfectly still, they would only see things that move.

Comment: To me, all these descriptions of speedy movements all seem applicable to much smaller birds than crows. I get to watch crows a lot, Hooded crows being very common hereabouts, and wouldn't describe them as flicking or waggling. Their size makes the movement seem much more purposeful and I don't think I would describe a crow as doing anything other than 'turning' its head.

Comment: @AnoE Yes. Read the end of Kace36's answer. You are absolutely correct.

Comment: @Spagirl I believe you are correct. I only picked a crow because it seemed to be the most common bird I could think of at the moment (perhaps I should have chosen a pigeon). I was originally going to use a chicken for my example, as I grew up on a chicken farm, but I knew that many people may have not seen how chickens act. They move their heads so fast sometimes their comb smacks their eyes! Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flicked is actually a great option in your original question. Here are some more:

[Jerked](https://www.google.com/search?q=flick%20definition&oq=flick%20definition&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.2090j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=jerk)

> a quick, sharp, sudden movement.

[Twitched](https://www.google.com/search?q=flick%20definition&oq=flick%20de&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.1764j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=twitch)

> give or cause to give a short, sudden jerking or convulsive movement.

I like flicked. You could also choose to use an adverb like abruptly to emphasize further:

> **The crow abruptly flicked its head, wary of my presence, saccading his beady eyes in my direction.**

Saccades are the quick eye movements that many animals, in particular birds, make. Humans do it too. For example when reading we make quick saccades to go from word to word and line to line.

Here is an article about the quick neck turning and saccading of bird's eyes:

[Link to: Why do birds turn their neck so fast and saccade?](https://geekswipe.net/science/biology/why-do-birds-turn-their-neck-so-fast/)

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! Flicked is indeed a nice word for the case. I cannot express how much I appreciate you bringing the anatomical aspect into the discussion. Now I know why birds do this! I will definitely be taking _saccades_ into my vocabulary. Such a descriptive word for a tiny little piece of movement. I love it.

Comment: Flicked is the best choice and I upvote; congrats also to OP @Psychobagger for already thinking of it and putting it in the question. Dometimes the word you think of is *already the best option* and we only need to confirm it.

Comment: @Psychobagger you are welcome, and keep taking active part in this English.StackExchange website!

Comment: Can bird's eye saccades be noted with the naked eye? These researchers had to glue things the chickens eyeballs when studying chicken eye and head movements? http://jeb.biologists.org/content/jexbio/97/1/217.full.pdf

Comment: I'd definitely advise against "saccade" in non-technical writing. It's the sort of word that has your readers reaching for the dictionary, destroying immersion in the story.

Comment: @Spagirl You can see the eye movements in humans. I'm unsure with birds. I would imagine it's much faster. I've learned about them b/c of Evelyn Wood's early research into speed reading. We are limited in our reading speed largely b/c of these saccading movements along with something known as subvocalization. Basically we focus our eyes for a split second to focus on a word, better readers multiple words, entire sentences, or in extreme cases, whole paragraphs. We quickly move them to focus again. I would imagine the glued on items were there for calculating & tracking chicken eye movement.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Agree. You probably should be careful with it's usage. However, that being said this is how we increase our vocabularies :) But, yes, I might modify for a more general or less academic audience to: "darting".

Comment: @Kace36 Yes, I understood what saccading was, that's why I doubted that it was something you'd note in birds without equipment. I looked up something to back up that doubt. I don't think the purpose of increasing vocabulary is to deploy words that we think need explaining to our audience.

Answer (score 3):

A good word for this might be:

> Swivel

It might suggest a more purposeful movement than jerk and twitch.

Comment: I do not know why that word escaped me. It has a good sound. Thank you for posting.